# Image upload error- amazon s3 - in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, file-upload, amazon-s3

I uploaded a image to amazon s3 using the following code

```
$s3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3();
$s3->putObject("bucket/" . $companyname . "/" . $filename, file_get_contents($file), array(Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_ACL_HEADER =>
                    Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_ACL_PUBLIC_READ));
```

But the size showing in the amazon s3 is 0 bytes ?

Any Solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the object is created in S3 but it's empty (0 bytes) then it's very likely that the problem is with the data that you're trying to send. Check if `file_get_contents($file)` does in fact return some data.

Comment: yes you are right...the problem is in it...$file should be the temporary name of the image.